# dropped table still exists in SQLAlchemy MetaData

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am working through some very basic SQLAlchemy exercises and, for whatever reason, am feeling very stumped at the moment. I've read through the SQLAlchemy Unified Tutorial already to gain a basic understanding of the tool, yet this issue evades me.

I am trying to first create a table, then drop it. I am using the 'print' statement at the end to list tables after the operations. The code and output are below.

Why does 'test deck' still appear in the metadata, even after the DROP statement is executed?

**CODE**

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo = True)
metadata_obj = MetaData()

with engine.connect() as conn:
    table_obj = Table('test deck', metadata_obj, Column('Name', String, primary_key = True))
    metadata_obj.create_all(conn)
    metadata_obj.tables['test deck'].drop(conn)

metadata_obj.reflect(engine)
print(metadata_obj.tables.keys())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2023-09-17 14:22:28,844 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-09-17 14:22:28,844 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("test deck")
2023-09-17 14:22:28,844 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-09-17 14:22:28,844 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA temp.table_info("test deck")
2023-09-17 14:22:28,844 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-09-17 14:22:28,845 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE "test deck" (
    "Name" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("Name")
)


2023-09-17 14:22:28,845 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00006s] ()
2023-09-17 14:22:28,845 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
DROP TABLE "test deck"
2023-09-17 14:22:28,845 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00006s] ()
2023-09-17 14:22:28,845 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
2023-09-17 14:22:28,845 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-09-17 14:22:28,845 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite~_%' ESCAPE '~' ORDER BY name
2023-09-17 14:22:28,845 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-09-17 14:22:28,846 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type='table' AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite~_%' ESCAPE '~' ORDER BY name
2023-09-17 14:22:28,846 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-09-17 14:22:28,846 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
dict_keys(['test deck'])
```

Comment: Try using `with engine.begin() as conn:` instead of `with engine.connect() as conn:` and see if that helps

Comment: It produces the same result - the key name still appears in the print output

Comment: Try `metadata_obj.clear()` before `metadata_obj.reflect(engine)`

Comment: That worked! Is it accurate to say that the TABLE was in fact dropped from the DB but not from the MetaData object?

Comment: That sounds right.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping a table apparently does not remove it from the MetaData, even if we use `metadata_obj.drop_all(engine, tables=[…])` to drop it.

```py
table_obj = Table(
    "test deck", metadata_obj, Column("Name", String, primary_key=True)
)
other_table = Table(
    "other_table", metadata_obj, Column("Name", String, primary_key=True)
)
metadata_obj.create_all(engine)
"""
CREATE TABLE "test deck" (
    "Name" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("Name")
)
CREATE TABLE other_table (
    "Name" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("Name")
)
"""
print(metadata_obj.tables.keys())
# dict_keys(['test deck', 'other_table'])  # as expected

table_to_remove = metadata_obj.tables['test deck']
metadata_obj.drop_all(engine, tables=[table_to_remove])
"""
DROP TABLE "test deck"
"""
print(metadata_obj.tables.keys())
# dict_keys(['test deck', 'other_table'])  # still there
```

We can either `.clear()` the MetaData object and reflect it (as in the comments to the question), or just `.remove()` the table from the current MetaData object

```py
metadata_obj.remove(table_to_remove)
print(metadata_obj.tables.keys())
# dict_keys(['other_table'])  # gone now
```